# Reflect on class declared in a Groovy script

Tags: java, groovy

Is there a way to obtain reflection data on class declared in a Groovy script that has been evaluated via a GroovyClassLoader parseClass method?

How exactly i can create instance of Customer from java code?

```
package project

public class Customer extends Entity {
    public String name
    String description
    Date updateDate
}

def run() {
    Workflow workflow = new Workflow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();

Class compiledClass = gcl.parseClass(src);

// usually we wait for "contract" class implemented in groovy, i.e Entity
Entity groovyEntity = (Entity ) compiledClass.newInstance();

// as yet, we don't know, implementation has name

String name = compiledClass.getName();
```